# Angular filter Observable array

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an Observable array and I want to filter/find the Project by name. When I try to use the filter option it is saying

[image]

ProjectService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Project } from "../classes/project";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

import { Http } from '@angular/http';


@Injectable()
export class ProjectService {

  private projects: Observable<Project[]>;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.loadFromServer();
  }

  getProjects(): Observable<Project[]> {
    return this.projects;
  }

  private loadFromServer() {
    this.projects = this.http.get('/api/projects').map(res => res.json());
  }

  getProjectByName(name: String) {
    return this.projects.filter(proj => proj.name === name);
  }


}
```

Project Class

```
export class Project {
    public name: String;
    public miniDesc: String;
    public description: String;
    public category: String[];
    public images: any[];
}
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

it should be:

```
getProjectByName(name: String) {
  return this.projects
    .map(projects => projects.filter(proj => proj.name === name));
}
```

you misunderstood about filter operator. The operator using to filter data return from stream. Your stream return array of object, so you need `filter array` to get you needed value.

The solution above will return an array after filtered, if you wanna get only one value, using following solution

```
getProjectByName(name: String) {
  return this.projects
    .map(projects => {
      let fl = projects.filter(proj => proj.name === name);
      return (fl.length > 0) ? fl[0] : null;
    });
}
```

Comment: You can also just write a for-loop inside the map arrow function which returns the first value that satisfies the condition: `.map(xs => { for (let x of xs) if (/*cond*/) return x; return null; })` etc.

Comment: Very nice solution provided by @Tiep Phan, only small note. Solution above work for array with primitive types, if you want to filter objects you can do something like:
`tasks.filter((item) => this.tasks.map((task) => task.id).indexOf(item.id) < 0`

Answer (score -1):

In your Service you can define `<any>` type or `Project[]` type to return the response value and same could be continue with filter. e.g. `<any>res.json()` or `<Project[]>res.json()`

and also update your class as suggested by @Sajeetharan

ProjectService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Project } from "../classes/project";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

import { Http } from '@angular/http';


@Injectable()
export class ProjectService {

  private projects: Observable<Project[]>;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.loadFromServer();
  }

  getProjects(): Observable<Project[]> {
    return this.projects;
  }

  private  loadFromServer(): Observable<any> {
    this.projects = this.http.get('/api/projects').map((res: Response)=> <any>res.json());
  }

  getProjectByName(name: string) {
    return this.projects.filter(proj => proj.name === name);
  }   
}
```

*always write your filters, conditions or manipulation in component not in services.