# How to filter using TS/Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Data model in ts:

```
export class PO {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  submitted: boolean = false;
}
```

Service, to get all POs

```
getPO() {
    return this.http
      .get<PO[]>(this.poUrl)
      .pipe(map(data => data), catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

to get only those **submitted = true**, following this [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43430715/angular-filter-observable-array),

```
getSubmitted() {
    return this.http
    .get<PO[]>(this.poUrl)
    .pipe(map(data => data.find(data => data.submitted === true)), catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

it still returns everything, tried data.filter(), the find/filter is not in effect.

Comment: You may need to provide an example of how the data comes in specifically for you prior to the `map()`. You could maybe utilize `tap()` to console log `data` before `map()` is executed. Also, `find()` will at most return a single element in an array.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky agree on find(), but tried filter() too.

Comment: You may want to show how `getSubmitted()` is executed and the data consumed in your component to get a full picture.

Comment: component: `ngOnInit() { this.getSubmitted();}`  html: `<ul> <li *ngFor="let p of PO">...`

Comment: Make sure the response is actually the data. Also you can use the rxjs `filter` instead of using `map` and then JavaScript Array `filter`.

Comment: Did any of these answers help you?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how entirely you are referencing and rendering the results of the `getSubmitted()` by the comment provided of `<li *ngFor="let p of PO">` there may be issues with clashing of variables given your data model object is called `PO` and the results are looping through a variable also called `PO`. Or assignment to a local variable of type `PO[]` is simply isn't happening. Try the following to filter and render `PO` objects with `submitted` property of boolean `true`:

```
getSubmitted() {
  return this.http
    .get<PO[]>(this.poUrl)
    .pipe(
      // tap(response => console.log(response)), to check/log structure before map()
      // assumes along lines of [{id:1, name:'foo', submitted:false}, {id:2, name:'bar', submitted:true}]
      map(data => data.filter(d => d.submitted)), 
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

Here are a couple approaches of how you can use to consume the data being returned from a successful `http.get()`.

```
submitted$: Observable<PO[]>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.submitted$ = this.getSubmitted();
}

// <li *ngFor="let p of submitted$ | async">
```

Or:

```
submitted: PO[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
  this.getSubmitted()
    .subscribe(submitted => this.submitted = submitted);
}

// <li *ngFor="let p of submitted">
```

Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mjtsb3) showing filtering functionality in action based on `submitted` object property of `PO`. It provides an example with and without an [Async Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe).

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying your API response on front-end. It will diffcult for to manage on different platforms. I prefered creating two WebAPI services. 
One for getting data where submitted is flag is true. 
Second service where flag is false.

**Reason:** In future if you planning to develop mobile app, then you have to hard code you logic in mobile app too.

Service data should be straight.

Answer (score 0):

```
data;
filteredData;

getPO() {
   return this.http.get<PO[]>(this.poUrl).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.data = data;
        this.filteredData = data;
      }
   );
}

getSubmitted() {
   this.filteredData = this.data.filter( el => el.submitted === true);
}
```

Then in your html, in your ngFor, if you have to iterate filteredData,

```
 *ngFor="let row of filteredData"
```

this way you don't download 2 times

Warning *** filter must be on the private array, not de data returned form the http call.