# Using map and filter in RxJs 6 (Ionic/Angular) is not working properly in object array, filter ignored

Tags: angular, ionic3, rxjs6

Does anybody know why this filter after mapping, is not working?

When I do this:

```
this.cacheService.getMainCache().pipe( map(val => val.list)).subscribe((val) => {
  console.log(val);
}, (error) => {
  console.log('Error: ', error);
});
```

I get this array of objects:
[image]

I need to filter this array and return only one, the one with the name property equal to some string, when I add the filter operator to the pipe nothing happens, I suppose nothing is filtered:

```
this.cacheService.getMainCache().pipe(map(val => val.list), filter((item: any) => item.name == 'profile')).subscribe((val) => {
  console.log(val);
}, (error) => {
  console.log('Error: ', error);
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your snippet is the type of item. You expect the filter function to filter the items. But in your case, item is the whole array itself. Since the array does not have a property "name", nothing is showing at the subscriber.
I suggest to use proper typing.

you have two options:

1. use standard javascript filter:

```js
this.cacheService.getMainCache().pipe(
    map(val => val.list.filter((item: any) => item.name == 'profile'))
).subscribe((val) => {
    console.log(val);
}, (error) => {
  console.log('Error: ', error);
});
```

2. convert your array into individual values and filter by rxjs filter operator, then pack them into array again:

```js
this.cacheService.getMainCache().pipe(
        map(val => val.list),
        concatAll(),
        filter((item: any) => item.name == 'profile')),
        toArray()
    ).subscribe((val) => {
        console.log(val);
    }, (error) => {
      console.log('Error: ', error);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all, but I managed to solve it chaining the pipes, my mistake:

```
this.cacheService.getMainCache()
  .pipe(switchMap((val) => from(val.list)))
  .pipe(filter((item: any) => item.name == 'profile'))
  .subscribe((val) => {
  console.log(val);
}, (error) => {
  console.log('Error: ', error);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this @devnosaur, it may solve your issue. for more about Observable filter have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43430835/9764133)

```
 this.cacheService.getMainCache().map((value: any)=> value.filter(val=> val.name === 'profille')).subscribe((val) => {
      console.log(val);
    }, (error) => {
      console.log('Error: ', error);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but no, I don't mean the "javascript filter" but the Observable filter. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Error:  TypeError: value.filter is not a function

Answer (score 0):

@devnosaur, Your most recent update where you chain pipes, the chained pipes are actually unnecessary. The most effective change you made was `switchMap(val => from(val.list)` which has the same effect as

`map(val => val.list),
concatAll()`

that A. Winnen recommended above. In my opinion, even though it is an extra line, doing map then concatAll() communicates much better, whereas using a flattening operator (switchMap) on a created observable (from) seems hacky.