# Does the filter operator behave differently when applied to an Observable created by from operator compared to when applied to a BehaviorSubject?

Tags: rxjs

I have defined variables person$ and source$ with two different approaches:

Approach 1: Defining person$ by using BehaviourSubject:

```
interface IPerson {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const person$ = new BehaviorSubject<IPerson[]>([
  { name: "amir", age: 20 },
  { name: "hosein", age: 10 },
]);
```

Approach 2: Defining variable using `from` operator:

```
const source$ =  from([
  { name: "amir", age: 20 },
  { name: "hosein", age: 10 }
]);
```

For finding person with age of less than 15, At first, I've  used `filter` operator as follows:

```
const filteredPerson$ = person$.pipe(
  filter((person) => person.age < 15),
  tap((person) => console.log("person", person)),
);

const observer1 = filteredPerson$.subscribe();
```

Using filter operator for variable person$ does not work.
But, using second approach, it works!.

```
const filtered$= source$.pipe(filter(person => person.age < 15));
const observer2= filtered$.subscribe(val => console.log(`${val.name}`));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular filter Observable array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43430715/angular-filter-observable-array)

Comment: Thanks for paying attention. I have added more details about my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Behaviour subject, will emit an array( `[ { name: "amir", age: 20 }, { name: "hosein", age: 10 }, ])` ), since an array is not an object, the filter condition will fail hence the entire result is filtered out!

while `from` takes an array and converts it into a stream of observables ( `first { name: "amir", age: 20 }, then { name: "hosein", age: 10 }` ) , emited one by one, so in this scenario, filter will receive a object and filter will work fine, since a single person will evalulated based on the condition

---

RxJs [`filter`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter) is used to filter out a observable stream not the data, the correct property to do this will be [`map`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map) since it will transform the response before reaching the subscribe! We use the javascript array `filter` operator to filter out the array values!

```
const filteredPerson$ = person$.pipe(
  map((persons) => persons.filter((person: any) => person.age < 5)),
  tap((person) => console.log("person", person)),
);

const observe1 = filteredPerson$.subscribe();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've modified my question and provide further details.